# django on_delete

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, pgadmin

I have two models in **django** Photos and Posts (foreign key between them).
`post = Posts.objects.get(pk=1)`
`post.delete() # all photos is deleted`. cascade delete. it's fine

but when I want delete from **pgadmin** error found... DETAIL:  `Key (id)=(1)` is still referenced from table "photos". why I can not delete from **pgadmin** ?

Comment: Because you haven't deleted the data that reference the post?

Comment: if i do not use django orm, I can not delete post. CASCADE has no effect from pgadmin. from orm, all is ok.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, CASCADE deleting and such things does Django by itself, not your database. PGAdmin works with the raw database.

But deleting from the shell should work:

```
python manage.py shell
Posts.objects.get(pk=1).delete()
```